# $y^2-7=x^3$ has no solutions in positive integers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, polynomials

Prove that there does not exist any positive integer solutions to the equation: $y^{2}-7=x^{3}$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan I have only figured out that both x and y will be of the form 7k+1. Trying to proceed with that but nothing significant as of now

Comment: It’s relatively easy to show $x$ must be odd.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews what next ?

Comment: Is it clear then that $y$ is even? Basically, tell me when you see that if $x,y$ are solutions then $y$ must be even and $x$ odd. (Note : this actually has an elementary solution so I'm trying to guide you through it)

Comment: Familiar with [elliptic curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve) ? [This](https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/21168/ce/2) says no integral solutions. @Richik

Comment: @TeresaLisbon yeah I got that y is even and x is odd

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin I really am not familiar with elliptic curves

Comment: Great. Now reduce the original equation mod $4$, to get $x \equiv 1 \mod 4$, so $(x+2) \equiv 3 \mod 4$.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon yeah I got your point. what next?

Comment: Great. Now reduce the original equation mod $4$, to get $x \equiv 1 \mod 4$, so $(x+2) \equiv 3 \mod 4$. Observe that $y^2+1 = x^3+8 = (x+2)(x^2-2x+4)$ so this shows that $y^2+1$ has a multiple which is congruent to $3$ modulo $4$. Conclude that there is a prime $p \equiv 3 \mod 4$ such that $y^2+1$ is a multiple of $p$. (Use the fact that if $z \equiv 3 \mod 4$ then $z$ must have a prime factor which is also congruent to $3 \mod 4$, and use prime factorization to see this fact) Can this happen?

Comment: @TeresaLisbon yeah sure. Thanks for the idea

Comment: Good to help. Now I can write an answer?

Comment: @TeresaLisbon yeah sure you may proceed to write an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per his suggestion, I rephrase what I said in the comments.

- We see that $x$ is odd and $y$ is even.
- Reducing the equation mod $4$ gives that $x \equiv 1 \mod 4$ and hence $(x+2) \equiv 3 \mod 4$.
- From $y^2 = x^3+7$, we get $y^2 +1 = x^3+8 = (x+2)(x^2-2x+4)$
- So $y^2+1$ is a multiple of $x+2$, which is $3 \mod 4$. It follows that $y^2+1$ is a multiple of some $p \equiv 3 \mod 4$ prime.
- However, this is a contradiction since $y^2 \equiv -1 \mod p$ does not have a solution for $p \equiv 3 \mod 4$.

---

Read up here : Mordell-Weil curves(and bound), Mordell equation, and in particular [Keith Conrad's document](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/mordelleqn1.pdf) on the subject. It is an interesting fact that $x^2=y^3+k$ for any integer $k$ has only finitely many solutions.